# Exportar dados Excel PHP Workbench Variavel

Tags: php, mysql, microsoft-excel

Estou com duvidas em relação ao gerar um excel com a query.

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$arquivo = 'Não autorizado .xls';
```

Primeira duvida:
Na parte do $arquivo será que consigo colocar uma variável para mudar o nome do arquivo?

```
// -- Cabeçalho do arquivo -------------------------------------
$html .= '<tr><td align="center"><b>Instalador</b></td>';
$html .= '<td align="center"><b>Morada</b></td>';
$html .= '<td align="center"><b>Email</b></td>';
$html .= '<td align="center"><b>Validade</b></td>';

</tr>';

for($i=1; $i<=$aux; $i ++){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT tb_trabalhador.Nome,Morada,Email,Validade from             
          tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on 
          tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join 
          tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id 
          inner join tb_funcoes on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_funcoes.id
          WHERE tb_trabalhador.id = $id = ".$i) or die(mysql_error());
          $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
          $html .= '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td><td>'.$row[1].'</td>
          <td>'.$row[2].'</td><td>'.$row[3].'</td></tr>';
  }
  $html .= '</table>';
```

Segunda duvida:
Eu vou exportar dados para o Excel com muitas datas. É possível eu exportar os dados para o Excel e onde as datas estiveres sido passadas em relação ao dia de hoje ficar um retangulo vermelho?

Comment: A sua questão ta muito ampla, poderia ser mais especifico?

Comment: Qual é a duvida ? Pode-me dizer para tentar explicar melhor?

Comment: Bom eu tenho a rotina que faz isso, pega um dado do banco Mysql e gera um ouput xls, que você recebe como download via navegador, tudo gerado pelo PHP... seria isso? Você precisa de um código que gere um xls (excel)?

Comment: Eu tenho o codigo que me dá o Excel. Mas ao gerar o Excel ele tem de ficar com um nome, nesse nome eu quero colocar o nome de uma variavel

Comment: Claro, que pode, mas, para chegar nessa página e nesse código como você faz, e na sua questão possui duas dúvidas?, na segunda se vai ter que alterar o código, não seria legal mandar o seu código no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei agora no corpo da pergunta o codigo

Answer (score 1):

No Código

```php
<?php
include("conectar.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$arquivo = $_GET['arquivo'];
```

você pode usar outro `$_GET['arquivo']` e atribuir a variável `$arquivo` para que você possa colocar o nome de sua preferência. Obs: Eu usuaria [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php) por motivos de segurança.

Exemplo com [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php)

```php
<?php
    include("conectar.php");
    $id      = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)
    $arquivo = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'arquivo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
```

E no código, pelo visto é pelo campo Validade então é o `row[3]` fiz a comparação da data atual com a data que vem do banco (`date('Y-m-d')`), não tem como eu saber se o código tem um erro, só fiz mesmo a adptação.

```php
<?php

// -- Cabeçalho do arquivo -------------------------------------
$html .= '<tr><td align="center"><b>Instalador</b></td>';
$html .= '<td align="center"><b>Morada</b></td>';
$html .= '<td align="center"><b>Email</b></td>';
$html .= '<td align="center"><b>Validade</b></td>';

$html .= '</tr>';

for($i=1; $i<=$aux; $i ++){
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT tb_trabalhador.Nome,Morada,Email,Validade from             
              tb_detalhe_trabalhador inner join tb_trabalhador on 
              tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_trabalhador.id inner join 
              tb_equipamentos on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_equipamentos.id 
              inner join tb_funcoes on tb_detalhe_trabalhador.id = tb_funcoes.id
              WHERE tb_trabalhador.id = $id = ".$i) or die(mysql_error());

          $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);       

          $html .= '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td><td>'.$row[1].'</td><td>'.$row[2].'</td>';
          //SE FOR DATA IGUAL A DE HOJE PINTE AS BORDAS DE VERMELHO
          if (date('Y-m-d') == $row[3]){
            $html .= '<td bordercolor="#FF0000" style="border:1px solid #FF0000; border-color:#FF0000">'.$row[3].'</td>';
          } else {
            $html .= '<td>'.$row[3].'</td>';
          }
          $html .= '</tr>';

  }
$html .= '</table>';
```

Comment: Só uma duvida. Na parte de comparar a data não tenho de fazer uma comparação com a data de hoje? IF date now() < $row[3]

Comment: `if (date('Y-m-d') == $row[3]){` aqui ta a conferencia da Data, entendeu ? Procure no código fazendo favor

Comment: <a id="link_abre" href="ExcelNaoAutorizado.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"> só com esta informação não consigo ir buscar o Nome desse id?

Comment: Consegue o id se o $_GET['id'] estiver preenchido, !se você quiser arquivo esse link seria: <a id="link_abre" href="ExcelNaoAutorizado.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&arquivo=<?php echo $_GET['arquivo']; ?>"> ... Como você gera essa link?

Comment: O primeiro link vem assim: echo '<li class="ui-widget-content"><h3><a href="NaoautorizadoMostrar.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</h3></a></li>';

Comment: <li class="ui-widget-content"><h3><a href="NaoautorizadoMostrar.php?id='.$exibe['id'].'&arquivo='.$exibe['Nome'].'">'.$exibe['Nome'].'</h3></a><‌​/li> vai sair com o nome !!! agora