# Chamar Variavel para nome Ficheiro php

Tags: php, variáveis

Estou com um problema em chamar o nome da variavel para o nome do Ficheiro Excel.
Tenho de colocar o nome da Variavel no $arquivo.
A variavel nome vem do Select * ...

```
 //--- Fazendo o preenchimento inicial --------------------------
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
 //- Definimos o nome do arquivo que será exportado -------------
 $arquivo = 'Empresa Não Autorizada '.$row[1]'.xls';
```

Da-me este erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.xls''

Comment: Olá. De onde é que vem a variável nome? Onde é que está definida?

Comment: A sintaxe do seu código, além de estar errada, não mostra relação com sua dúvida.

Comment: Quero que seja utilizada quando é chamada pela query a baixo

Comment: @user3253195 Aconselho-a a editar a pergunta, corrigir o sintaxe e explicar melhor a sua pergunta. Da forma como leio parece que está a tentar criar a variável `$arquivo`e não consegue.

Comment: Estou com um problema ao colocar o nome do arquivo com a Variavel $NOME

Comment: @user3253195 da forma como tem o código estruturado, `$Nome` nunca poderá vir do `SELECT *`. Terá de colocar a declaração de `$arquivo` depois de `$row=mysql_fetch_array($sql);`. E ficará `$arquivo = ' Não Autorizada '.$row.'.xls';`. (Se o percebi bem).

Comment: @user3253195 falta um ponto após o `$row[1]`: $arquivo = 'Não Autorizada ' . $row[1] . '.xls';

Comment: so uma duvida. Posso ter o Select com o *? ou tenho de definir um a um  todos os campos?

Comment: @user3253195 se tiver a certeza que o schema da BD não vai mudar e que o campo que quer está sempre na posição 1 não há problema. No entanto considere que está a seleccionar as colunas todas (podem ser duas ou podem ser 20) quando na realidade só vai utilizar uma.

Comment: Mas tendo varias tabelas não gera problema?

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in da-me este erro

Comment: @user3253195 Quando faz o `Select * from Tabela` só está a fazer select a **uma** tabela, não a várias. O `*` significa que vai seleccionar todas as colunas da tabela. Relativamente ao undefined offset a query pode só ter um campo (os arrays em PHP começam os seus indices em zero, logo se só houver uma coluna em `$row` teria de ser `$row[0]`.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser off-topic porque é sobre um erro tipográfico cuja solução não beneficia nenhum visitante futuro.

Comment: E não é a mesma coisa que você já tinha perguntado em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17371/exportar-dados-excel-php-workbench-variavel?

Answer (score 3):

Falta-lhe um ponto antes de `xls`:

```
$arquivo = 'Empresa Não Autorizada ' . $row[1] . '.xls';
```